# how to change grease pencil radius using brackets []

Tags: grease-pencil

brackets not working for changing the brush radius like it does for sculpting/texture painting. Is there a a keymap to get this to work similarly?

Comment: would be great to have this. I tried manually adding it to the keymap, copying the brush.scale_size settings from sculpt into GP draw mode, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't edit the keymap to get this to work at the time this question was asked, **BUT** the shortcuts have been added to the 3.0 alpha build:

> New Bracket keymaps ([, ]) to increase and decrease brush size. ([c58bf31aed](https://developer.blender.org/rBc58bf31aeddd))

[3.0 Grease Pencil release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Grease_Pencil)

[Daily builds download page](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/)